# C - Bitwise concatenation causing missing information

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I have five short type variables which I want to concatenate them into an 32 bits unsigned int type. I need to concatenate five short variables. The names of those variables are called opcode(5 bits), reg1(4 bits), reg2(4 bits), reg3(4 bits), extension(3 bits) and addr_constant(12 bits). Now my code does not work for one case which I do not know why. I listed my code below.

The purpose of this code is to translate certain values into a 32 bits machine instruction, which means even though I got the equivalent value, I still need to have a 32 bits instruction.

```
...
unsigned int *const word;
unsigned short opcode = 1;
unsigned short reg1 = 3; 
unsigned short reg2 = 4;
unsigned short reg3 = 5;
unsigned short extension = 0;
unsigned int addr_constant = 0;

unsigned int machine_word = 0;
machine_word = machine_word | (opcode << 27);
machine_word = machine_word | (reg1 << 23);
machine_word = machine_word | (reg2 << 19);
machine_word = machine_word | (reg3 << 15);

machine_word = machine_word | (extension << 12);
machine_word = machine_word | addr_constant;

*word = machine_word
return 0;
...
```

The output in binary form should be:

```
0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000.
```

But right now it is:

```
1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000.
```

As you can see, it misses the first 4 zeros.

In the following test "word" is: unsigned int *const word. And in the end of the code above, I wrote "*word = machine_word". In the test, it compares: "word == 0x09a28000"
I failed the following test.

```
assert(word == 0x09a28000);
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", machine_word);` cannot possibly print `1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000`. Please show the code that does the printing.

Comment: It's a simple presentational issue I guess. Lets say you have the (decimal) value `2`, do you write it as `02`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just transfer decimal value to its corresponding binary value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. But I left shift 27 bits. Shouldn't the leftmost bits of machine_word not be "00001"?

Comment: `0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000` the same thing as `1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000.`, just as `02` is the same as `2` .

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, but right now I have a test which compared my output with the one with "0000" prefix. This caused me failed test. Is it possible for me to filled in those bits?

Comment: What is the decimal value then?

Comment: How is the test written? What is the output of `printf("%08x\n", machine_word)` then?

Comment: @KaiweiLuo maybe your test is wrong. Please [Edit] your question and show it. Also read this [mcve].

Comment: @KamilCuk "assert(machine_word == 0x09a28000)". As you can see, I miss a zero

Comment: @KaiweiLuo your code with `assert(machine_word == 0x09a28000);` works fine here, please post a [MCVE].

Comment: You "can't" miss a zero. `unsigned int` variable has 4 bytes on your architecture, you have 8 bits per byte, so it has 32 bits. No matter what you do. The `assert(0x09a28000 == 0x9a28000)` will  not fail. also the `assert(0x0000000009a28000 == 0x09a28000);` will also not fail.

Comment: "I failed on `assert(word == 0x09a28000);`" - Maybe because `word` is not the same as `machine_word`????

Comment: Again, and as already said by others as well, you don't normally write leading zeroes in *any* numbers, no matter the base.

Comment: You code works, see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJWSAYk5Q) for live version.

Comment: @KaiweiLuo Please post the verbatim output of your program. [This small test program](https://www.ideone.com/44Q7mD) works fine, it doesn't assert as expected.

Comment: @AlexLop. Good point !!

Comment: Also please post the result you get, maybe your compiler does *interesting* things when you shift `unsigned short` more than 16 bits to the left... :)

Comment: @AlexLop.  word is: unsigned int *const word. And in the end of the code, I wrote "*word = machine_word". In the test, it compares: "word == 0x09a28000"

Comment: @KaiweiLuo please post a [MCVE], otherwise it's hard to answer. Click here ---> [mcve].

Comment: To summarize: The code you have shown works in the sense it produces the desired bits in `machine_word`. One flaw is that `machine_word | (opcode << 27)` should be `machine_word | ((unsigned int) opcode << 27)` to avoid overflow if bit 4 (value 16) of `opcode` is set. However, you have stated conflicting requirements and descriptions of the behavior. You say your code fails the test `assert(word == 0x09a28000)` but also say “The output in binary form should be 0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000.”…

Comment: … Is the program supposed to set word to 0x09a28000 or is it supposed to output “0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000” or both? Also, the code appears to set `word` to the value 0x09a28000, so we do not see why the test would be failing. That suggests the actual code that is failing is not shown in the question. You should provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it was supposed to set word to 0x09a28000.

Comment: @KaiweiLuo Either post the whole code r the minimal code which represents the issue you are talking about, or close this question at all. Everyone here keeps on saying that the posted code is clean and works so the problem is not in the code you posted. By guessing, we won't get any further.

Comment: @KaiweiLuo To clarify what everyone is asking, please post a self-contained piece of code that others can compile and run **as-is** that reproduces your problem.  Otherwise, you won't get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the issue is just the result interpretation. I've run the following code, which is based on the algorithm you provided with some modifications on the logical operations and the result printing. The core logic of the operation remains unvaried from what you posted, so maybe the result is misread.

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, mask;

    unsigned short opcode = 1;
    unsigned short reg1 = 3; 
    unsigned short reg2 = 4;
    unsigned short reg3 = 5;
    unsigned short extension = 0;
    unsigned int addr_constant = 0;

    unsigned int machine_word = 0;
    machine_word |= opcode << 27;
    machine_word |= reg1 << 23;
    machine_word |= reg2 << 19;
    machine_word |= reg3 << 15;

    machine_word |= extension << 12;
    machine_word |= addr_constant;

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--){
            printf("%d", (machine_word & 0x00000001 << (4 * i + j)) >> (4 * i + j));
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code gives the following output:

```
0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

This should be the result your are searching for, it corresponds to the unsigned integer value of `161644544` (`0x9A28000`).

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to print the binary value on the console without resorting to masking and loop. Unfortunately I'm not aware on how to do so

Answer (score 2):

Just use bitfields--they're designed for this.

```
struct all_the_things {
  unsigned opcode : 5;
  unsigned reg1 : 4;
  unsigned reg2 : 4;
  unsigned reg3 : 4;
  unsigned extension : 3;
  unsigned addr_constant : 12;
};
```

Once you've populated such a struct, you can convert it to a 32-bit integer like this:

```
uint32_t num;
memcpy(&num, &things, 4);
```

(Don't worry, an optimizing compiler won't really call a function to copy 4 bytes.)

Comment: Unfortunately my teacher doesn't allow us to use anything outside of the lecture. So, I can only use bit shifting instead of bit field

Comment: (0) This answer does not provide the concatenated bits in a single number, numeral, or output string, so it does not satisfy the specification that “The output in binary form should be 0000 1001 1010 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000.” (1) This answer introduces implementation-dependent issues of bit-field ordering and the storage unit used for bit-fields that are not present in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I've added a bit to the answer to show how to convert it to a `uint32_t`.  The implementation-dependant part is technically correct but code like this is known to work on the compilers we all know and love.